Update of didChangeDependencies (Flutter)
I have a Dashboard homepage that allows me to access another page called Brand.
GoRoute(
          name: DashboardPage.routeName,
          path: DashboardPage.routeName,
          builder: (context,state) => const DashboardPage(),
          routes: [
            GoRoute(
              name: BrandPage.routeName,
              path: BrandPage.routeName,
              builder: (context,state) => const BrandPage(),
            )

My goal is to be able to add a new brand on the Brand page, send the name of this brand to my database, and then have my page (in the form of a ListView) refresh instantly to show the newly added brand.
To optimize the functioning of this system, I have two functions,:
addBrand to add a new brand to my database (in a file Db_helper):
static Future<void> addBrand(Brand brand) {
    final doc = _db.collection(collectionBrand).doc();
    brand.id = doc.id;
    return doc.set(brand.toMap());
}

getAllBrands to retrieve all the brands from my database and stock them in a list defined in my provider:
getAllBrands() {
    DbHelper.getAllBrands().listen((snapshot) {
      brandList = List.generate(snapshot.docs.length, (index) => Brand.fromMap(snapshot.docs[index].data()));
    });
    notifyListeners();
  }

To try to solve my problem, it seems that I simply need to call my getAllBrands function at the "right moment" and then display all the elements of the brandList in my ListView.
Consumer<TelescopeProvider>(
        builder: (context, provider, child) =>
        provider.brandList.isEmpty
            ? const Center(child: Text("Brand Not Found"))
            : ListView.builder(
          itemCount: provider.brandList.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            final brand = provider.brandList[index];
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(brand.name),
            );
          },
        ),
      )

To avoid constantly regenerating my data, I decided to refresh my data whenever there are changes in the dependencies of the Dashboard (I want to access other pages besides Brand, so I want to centralize everything in the Dashboard). Therefore, I wrote in DashboardPage:
@override void didChangeDependencies() { 
Provider.of<TelescopeProvider>(context, listen: false).getAllBrands(); super.didChangeDependencies(); 
}

However, every time I add an element in Brand, the page does not update immediately; I have to return to the Dashboard and then go back to Brand to see my new list.
I think I understand why this is happening because when I return to the Dashboard from Brands, the Dashboard is reconstructed, which calls the didChangeDependencies function. However, when I stay on Brand and add my element, there is no change in context, and thus didChangeDependencies is not triggered.
Yet, I saw a video doing the same thing, and Brand was updating directly. Therefore, I am a bit lost both on the conditions that cause didChangeDependencies to be called and especially on how to solve my problem.

You have the function getAllBrands for what i'm seeing its a stream that you starts to listen, did you tried to move the notifyListeners to inside the .listen instead of calling it after? theoretically when you call the addBrand your stream listener function should be called, then the notifyListeners its supposed to update the brand list from your page, hope it helps. 
This Question might help you to understand more about the didChangeDependencies
